# Android edittext auto grow with text and pushing things down

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

Yes, this is yet another edittext grow question on SO. And yes I've already gone through all those edittext grow questions. But this ones a bit specific.

UI:

[image]

A simple android layout with edittext and button below it. When text is less, the edittext view is still covering whole screen leaving space for button below.

Once user starts entering text, edittext grows vertically to accommodate text. At the same time, the button should also kept pushing downwards to let edittext grow.

User can vertically scroll through screen to view full text.

UI after entering significant text:

[image]

Here's the layout with edittext and button below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/background"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:fadingEdge="none"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:padding="13dp"
    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <!-- some fixed width image  -->
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/someimage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:src="@drawable/page_white_text" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/some"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/someimage"
            android:background="@null"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:minLines="10"
            android:minHeight="50dp"
            android:textColor="#222222"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:typeface="serif" >
            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:baselineAligned="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

This works more or less. But when I enter to much text, instead of pushing button downwards. It goes behind it like:

[image]

Any help here is much appreciated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my recommendation: inside the ScrollView, put a RelativeLayout in which you can place every element in a certain order using android:layout_below. For the auto-growing of your EditText, use this [solution](https://snipt.net/orastem/android-multiline-edittext-that-dynamically-increases-height-to-always-display-whole-text/).

Let's see an example:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center">
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/general2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_margin="20sp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textFirstOpinion"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/titleFirstOpinion"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="23sp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/fieldFirstOpinion"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/textFirstOpinion" 
        android:minHeight="80sp"
        android:isScrollContainer="true"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:gravity="top|left" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/fieldFirstOpinion"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="37sp"
        android:textSize="23sp"
        android:text="@string/textSendButton"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="10dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding android:layout_below="@id/some" in your LinearLayout like

```
   <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:baselineAligned="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_below="@id/some" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Hi Vinit, please see comment on above ans.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want the button to be at the bottom of the page, add the following line

```
android:layout_below="@+id/some"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

in your LinearLayout code here like

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/some"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:baselineAligned="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
```

Also make sure the `layout:height` parameter of EditText is set to `wrap_content`
Try this and tell me if it works or not

Comment: Setting layout_below to id/some makes the button stick to edittext. I wanted edittext to be shown fullscreen and button to stick at the bottom. If text in edit text grows beyond screen, it should push the button below. This works partially :(